# postorder using tail recursion

Tags: algorithm, tail-recursion

i find this link, http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Algorithms/Q_25205171.html, which suggests a way to do postorder tail recursion. however, it uses 2 stacks, is there a way to do this with only one stack.  thanks!

below is the java code pasted from the link above:

```
public static final <T> void postorder(Tree<T> root) {
    Stack<Tree<T>> stack = new Stack<Tree<T>>();
    Stack<Tree<T>> traversal = new Stack<Tree<T>>();
    stack.push(root);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      Tree<T> node = stack.pop();
      if (node.right != null) 
        stack.push(node.right);
      }
      if (node.left != null) {
        stack.push(node.left);
      }
      traversal.push(node);
    }
    while (!traversal.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println(traversal.pop().value.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: please use the `{}` button in the editor to format code next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the code needs to be structured differently. A proper stack-based simulation of a recursive algorithm should *keep* a node on the stack until the node and its children have been completely traversed. The stack should contain instances of a class that contains information about how many children have been traversed, say:

```
public class StackElement<T> {
    public Tree<T> node;
    public int numTraversedChildren;
}
```

(using public fields for simplicity). Whenever you push a node onto the stack, push a `StackElement` that refers to that node and where `numTraversedChildren` is 0. In the top of the loop, peek (don't pop) the stack to find the top element. If and only if `numTraversedChildren == 2`, you know that all children of this node have been traversed. In that case, you can process (in your case, print) that node and then pop it. Otherwise, keep the node on the stack, increment `numTraversedChildren`, and push either its left child (if the old value of `numTraversedChildren` was 0) or its right child (if the old value of `numTraversedChildren` was 1).

Note that when this approach is followed, the `while` loop and the push/pop operations on the stack are effectively simulating function calls: a push is a call, a pop is a return, and the stack maintains all parameters and local variables for each function invocation. The element at the top of the stack always represents the function that is currently executing.

Comment: thanks for the details reply.  this basically adds another data member to the node.  if we go with this approach, we can add a visited flag and a parent pointer to the node, and not using the stack at all.

Comment: @user612308: That's correct, but keep in mind that that would mix up the data structure itself (the tree) with the algorithm-specific data (the `visited` flag and possibly the `parent` pointer). This is perfectly fine (after all, data structures and algorithms are tightly coupled) if the only purpose of the tree is to perform this algorithm once, but if the tree is used elsewhere in the program, I'd recommend keeping the algorithm data out of the tree.

Comment: that's a valid point, it's something i have been thinking about as well.  thanks again for the help Aasmund!