# How to walk an AST with tail recursion in Clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, antlr, antlr3, tail-recursion

I have an ANTLR3 AST which I need to traverse using a post-order, depth-first traversal which I have implemented as roughly the following Clojure:

```
(defn walk-tree [^CommonTree node]
  (if (zero? (.getChildCount node))
    (read-string (.getText node))
    (execute-node
      (map-action node)
      (map walk-tree (.getChildren node)))))))
```

I would like to convert this to tail recursion using loop...recur, but I haven't been able to figure out how to effectively use an explicit stack to do this since I need a post-order traversal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of producing a tail recursive solution which traverses the tree and visits each node, you could produce a **lazy sequence of the depth first traversal** using the `tree-seq` function and then get the text out of each object in the traversal. **Lazy sequences never blow the stack** because they store all the state required to produce the next item in the sequence in the heap. They are very often used instead of recursive solutions like this where `loop` and `recur` are more diffacult.

I don't know what your tree looks like though a typical answer would look something like this. You would need to play with the "Has Children" "list of children" functions

```
(map #(.getText %) ;; Has Children?      List of Children    Input Tree
     (tree-seq #(> (.getChildCount #) 0) #(.getChildren %) my-antlr-ast))
```

If tree-seq does not suit your needs there are other ways to produce a lazy sequence from a tree. Look at the zipper library next.

Comment: Although I wish I could accept both this answer and the answer below which uses a stack, this really is the better solution even if it's not exactly what I had in mind.  Thank you for turning me on to a better way of thinking about this problem!

Comment: FWIW, tree-seq gives a pre-order traversal, not a post-order. Honestly, I think the simplest solution here is `clojure.walk/postwalk` and I would use that if possible. If there's truly a danger of blowing the stack then zippers could work, though it can be tricky to do a true post-order traversal with them. Regardless of their suitability for this particular problem, zippers are a wonderful tool to have in your arsenal :)

Answer (score 5):

As you mention, the only way to implement this using tail recursion is to switch to using an explicit stack. One possible approach is to convert the tree structure into a stack structure that is essentially a Reverse Polish notation representation of the tree (using a loop and an intermediate stack to accomplish this). You would then use another loop to traverse the stack and build up your result.

Here's a sample program that I wrote to accomplish this, using the Java code at [postorder using tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450316/postorder-using-tail-recursion) as an inspiration.

```
(def op-map {'+ +, '- -, '* *, '/ /})

;; Convert the tree to a linear, postfix notation stack
(defn build-traversal [tree]
  (loop [stack [tree] traversal []]
    (if (empty? stack)
      traversal
      (let [e (peek stack)
            s (pop stack)]
        (if (seq? e)
          (recur (into s (rest e)) 
                 (conj traversal {:op (first e) :count (count (rest e))}))
          (recur s (conj traversal {:arg e})))))))

;; Pop the last n items off the stack, returning a vector with the remaining
;; stack and a list of the last n items in the order they were added to
;; the stack
(defn pop-n [stack n]
  (loop [i n s stack t '()]
    (if (= i 0)
      [s t]
      (recur (dec i) (pop s) (conj t (peek s))))))

;; Evaluate the operations in a depth-first manner, using a temporary stack
;; to hold intermediate results.
(defn eval-traversal [traversal]
  (loop [op-stack traversal arg-stack []]
    (if (empty? op-stack)
      (peek arg-stack)
      (let [o (peek op-stack)
            s (pop op-stack)]
        (if-let [a (:arg o)]
          (recur s (conj arg-stack a))
          (let [[args op-args] (pop-n arg-stack (:count o))]
            (recur s (conj args (apply (op-map (:op o)) op-args)))))))))

(defn eval-tree [tree] (-> tree build-traversal eval-traversal))
```

You can call it as such:

```
user> (def t '(* (+ 1 2) (- 4 1 2) (/ 6 3)))
#'user/t
user> (eval-tree t)
6
```

I leave it as an exercise to the reader to convert this to work with a Antlr AST structure ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not skilled up on clojure, but I think I understand what you're looking for.

Here's some pseudocode.  The stack here in my pseudocode looks like a stateful object, but it's quite feasible to use an immutable one instead.  It uses something like O(depth of tree * max children per node) heap.

```
walk_tree(TreeNode node) {
    stack = new Stack<Pair<TreeNode, Boolean>>();
    push(Pair(node, True), stack)
    walk_tree_aux(stack);
}
walk_tree_aux(Stack<Pair<TreeNode, Boolean>> stack) { -- this should be tail-recursive
    if stack is empty, return;
    let (topnode, topflag) = pop(stack);
    if (topflag is true) {
        push Pair(topnode, False) onto stack);
        for each child of topnode, in reverse order:
            push(Pair(child, True)) onto stack
        walk_tree_aux(stack);
    } else { -- topflag is false
        process(topnode)
        walk_tree_aux(stack);
    }
}
```